# Calling a method from all the instances of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, instances

This question may sound a little weird, but I have been unable to find the answer so far, and I decided to ask here:

Is there a way to call a method from all the instances of a class without having to loop through each and every single instance manually?

#### Example:

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
instList = []

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #init stuff
        
        instList.append(self)

    def theThing(self):
        #do the thing

def allTheThings(il):
    for inst in il:
        inst.theThing()

allTheThings(instList)
```

This works pretty well normally, but it doesn't seem very efficient. Is there some way to streamline this into one or two lines of code?

Something like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #init stuff

    def theThing(self):
        #do the thing

SomeClass.instances.theThing()
```

or this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #init stuff

    def theThing(self):
        #do the thing

instancesOf(SomeClass).theThing()
```

This would be really helpful, as I plan on using this in many different ways: auto-killing everything at the end of a game, detecting various polygon-shaped buttons being clicked, anything that involves calling a single method on a bunch of instances.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you're doing it now, except that it is suspicious that you need this pattern very often. There is very likely a better way to accomplish what you are doing.

Comment: In what way does it not seem very efficient? What do you think is being done that doesn't need to happen? Except for the usage of a global variable, what you have seems fine.

Comment: "Is there a way to call a method from all the instances of a class without having to loop through each and every single instance manually?"

No, there isn't. Classes do not automatically keep track of all instances of themselves, so you'll have to implement this yourself.

Comment: martineau, I think that having to keep track of each instance by adding it to a variable is inefficient. Sure, it makes removing instances easier, but it doesn't seem like it would work very well with large numbers of instances, especially if I need to call the method in a `while True` loop, such as in PyGame.